# io.realm.RealmObject not found

Tags: android, realm

In my android library project, i install `Realm` as a Gradle plugin (as described in https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/).

When I add my library project (aar file) into my application project, it can not build with error "cannot access RealmObject
class file for io.realm.RealmObject not found"

I have to install realm plugin in application project to overcome this error. Anyone can help me this situation, i do not want install realm plugin in application project.

Comment: Please post your Gradle build files

Comment: Sounds like you need a module. Please take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/moduleExample/library.

Answer (score 0):

> i do not want install realm plugin in application project.

1. I afraid you have to.
2. Why not?

---

You could try to add those dependencies to your Application project by hand:

```
compile "io.realm:realm-android-library:$version"
compile "io.realm:realm-annotations:$version"
```