# Local aar-file project: class file for io.realm.RealmObject not found

Tags: android, realm

I've setup a Library project with the realm-plugin as described in the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/). I then use gradle assemble to build my aar-files, that I have included as a module in another application.
When I try to build the application, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot access RealmObject
class file for io.realm.RealmObject not found
```

My problem seems to be similar to: [io.realm.RealmObject not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763491/io-realm-realmobject-not-found). If I apply the realm-plugin in the application project, it works. He doesn't seem to reply to comments and get his question answered, which is why I'm trying now.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Added links to the complete gradle files.

Library (SDK) gradle files:
Project file: [SDK Project](https://gist.github.com/hauthorn/046bf969eec80681a74c5582f5300f9b)
App file: [SDK App](https://gist.github.com/hauthorn/e4a4a9dcb250c00acbbd1eee55a397d6)

Application (client app) gradle files:
Project file: [client Project](https://gist.github.com/hauthorn/99caa8983fd69135f656e54b126508d4)
App file: [client app](https://gist.github.com/hauthorn/be10aa7494b5c149b4bee0a26a3eb312)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but Christian will likely look at it some time today. Should he solve your problem, be sure to flag that other question as duplicate of this one

Comment: @TimCastelijns that sounds great. I will be available to post further information if needed.

Comment: You could declare a Realm module for library project: see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/moduleExample/library and https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/RealmModule.html. Using a module, you confine your Realm usage to the library.

Comment: @Hauthorn Can you add the full `build.gradle` files of your library and your app?

Comment: @larsgrefer I've added them now as gists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add those dependencies to your Application project by hand:

```
compile "io.realm:realm-android-library:$version"
compile "io.realm:realm-annotations:$version"
```

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't solve the problem. The error is still:
`Error:(72, 41) error: cannot access RealmObject
class file for io.realm.RealmObject not found`

Comment: According to your gists, you've added these dependencies to the library. Try adding them to the app

Comment: That will probably work, but I'm interested in the client NOT having to specify dependencies that should be provided by the library project.
Will try tomorrow to confirm.

Comment: This does work. However, I would like the client of the SDK to only add my library as a dependency, and not have to care about using the current version of Realm.

Comment: In this case you have to publish your library in a Maven (or Ivy) repository so the transitive dependencies can be handled

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you.